# Could not get unknown property 'a.b.c' for root project

Tags: gradle

I got some source code and was asked to build it. It was a Gradle project. So I changed to the project directory and ran:

```
$ gradle clean assemble
```

and the following error came up:

```
...
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'pcase'.
> Could not get unknown property 'postgresql.jdbc' for root project 'pcase' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
...
```

There is a `settings.gradle` file in the project folder too. It contains:

```
rootProject.name = 'pcase'
```

I took a look at `build.gradle` and found lots of occurrences like

```
${project['x']}
```

For example:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    ...
    // FlywayDB, JOOQ.
    classpath "org.postgresql:postgresql:${project['postgresql.jdbc']}"
    classpath "org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:${project['flywaydb.plugin.version']}"
    classpath "nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:${project['jooq.plugin.version']}"
    ...
```

What could be `${project['x']}`? Looks like associative array in bash and the build script tries to get the value of the key `'x'`.

But I didn't find the place in code where this array would be declared and initialized.

The question is: Is the project buildable or is it better to consult the company that worked at it before me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information provided, the project is perfectly buildable, to some certain extend. First of all, `project['a.b.c']` is Groovy syntax to access properties from the `project` object. They're referred to as [project properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties).

They can be set via

1. Project properties via command line: `gradle -Ppostgresql.jdbc=x.y.z`
2. System properties via command line: `gradle -Dorg.gradle.project.postgresql.jdbc=x.y.z`
3. System properties via `gradle.properties`: `org.gradle.project.postgresql.jdbc=x.y.z`

All 3 properties (`postgresql.jdbc`, `flywaydb.plugin.version`, `jooq.plugin.version`) denote the version numbers of the particular build script dependencies. However, which versions to use best is beyond my knowledge. I would certainly consult the respective project websites, [Maven artifact search](https://search.maven.org/) or simply ask the company.

- [org.postgresql:postgresql](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql) is the database JDBC driver and certainly depends on the database version.
- [org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-gradle-plugin) is for database migrations. Try with the latest version.
- I wasn't able to find [gradle-jooq-plugin](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin) on Maven central. It's most likely available on the [Gradle Plugin Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/).

Comment: I think you meant 'gradle.properties' file. After I created it and added 'postgresql.jdbc=x.y.z' and ran the build again the same error moved to the next dependency in the script. So it seems to work. I'll have to ask the company to name all the dependency versions.